# How to include sliderInput as label for pie()

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if it is possible to use the value from a sliderInput() as label for a chart. I tried to build it using reactive() but instead of displaying the value as label is displays a bunch of text (see reproducible example as included below).

Any hints how to solve are much appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

PT <- c(0.5, 0.5)
label1 <- c(data, 5)
label2 <- c(0, 0)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    fluidRow(column(width=6, plotOutput("P1", width = "30vw")), column(width = 6, plotOutput("P2", width = "30vw"))),
    sliderInput("S1", label = NULL, min = 0, max = 10, value = 5)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data <- reactive({ c(input$S1) })

    output$P1 <- renderPlot({
        pie(PT, labels = label1, init.angle = 90)
    })
    
    output$P2 <- renderPlot({
        pie(PT, labels = label2, init.angle = 90)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  output$P1 <- renderPlot({
    label1 <- c(input$S1, 5)
    pie(PT, labels = label1, init.angle = 90)
  })
```

Comment: indeed, this was the solution I was looking for. thanks a lot!